# error: no operator "<" matches these operands

Tags: c++, qt, stl, std

The error I receive:

> ```
> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386: 
> error: no operator "<" matches these operands
> operand types are: const QVector3D < const QVector3D
> { return __x < __y; }
> ```

I'm using `QVector3D` with `std::set` and `std::hypot`. Is there any approach to implement an overloaded `operator<` for `QVector3D` to be able to use it in my code?

```cpp
std::pair<QVector3D, QVector3D> NearestNeighbor::nearest_pair(std::vector<QVector3D> points)
{
     // // Sort by X axis
     std::sort( points.begin(), points.end(), [](QVector3D const &a, QVector3D const &b) { return a.x() < b.x(); } );

     // // First and last points from `point` that are currently in the "band".
     auto first = points.cbegin();
     auto last = first + 1;

     // // The two closest points we've found so far:
     auto first_point = *first;
     auto second_point = *last;

     std::set<QVector3D> band{ *first, *last };

     // // Lambda function to find distance
     auto dist = [] (QVector3D const &a, QVector3D const &b) { return std::hypot(a.x() - b.x(), a.y() - b.y()); };

     float d = dist(*first, *last);

     while (++last != points.end()) {
         while (last->x() - first->x() > d) {
             band.erase(*first);
             ++first;
         }

         auto begin = band.lower_bound({ 0, last->y() - d, 0 });
         auto end   = band.upper_bound({ 0, last->y() + d, 0 });

         assert(std::distance(begin, end) <= 6);

         for (auto p = begin; p != end; ++p) {
             if (d > dist(*p, *last)) {
                 first_point = *p;
                 second_point = *last;
                 d = dist(first_point, second_point);
             }
         }

         band.insert(*last);
     }
     return std::make_pair(first_point, second_point);
}
```

### UPDATE

With @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts help, the problem solved by replacing:

```
std::set<QVector3D> band{ *first, *last };
```

with:

```
auto customComparator = [](QVector3D const &a, QVector3D const &b) { return a.y() < b.y(); };
std::set<QVector3D, decltype (customComparator)> band({ *first, *last }, customComparator);
```

Also I can do this:

```
auto customComparator = [](QVector3D const &a, QVector3D const &b) { return a.y() < b.y(); };
std::set<QVector3D, decltype (customComparator)> band(customComparator);
band.insert(*first);
band.insert(*last);
```

Comment: [Why yes you can!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) But you need to figure out what < means for a `QVector3D` and it must allow [Strict weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have various possibilities. Yes, you can overload `operator<` as stated in the comment, but I would advise against it: you need a particular comparison function for this particular usecase, maybe somewhere else you'll need a different ordering. Unless the ordering relationship for a type is obvious I would suggest avoiding overloading the operator.

You can provide a custom comparison function, like in the following

```
auto customComparator = [](QVector3D const &a, QVector3D const &b) { return a.x() < b.x(); };

std::set<QVector3D, decltype(customComparator)> set(customComparator);

set.insert(*first)
```

To me it is unclear what the `band` set is trying to achieve, but since you are invoking upper and lower bound on the `y()`coordinate, maybe you want to compare on `y()` but this mean that two points having the same `y()` will be considered equal and `std::set` does not allow duplicates.

Otherwise, you can look into `std::unordered_set` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) which does not require ordering, but only that the element have `operator ==` and an hash function.

Edit: another alternative:
you can use `std::vector`and then use the free function `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` with custom compare function, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound

Comment: Thanks =) You are using `myCoord`, I wonder how `myCoord` is declared.

Comment: Apologies, myCoord was a type I created in a compiler to make sure that my syntax on the set was correct and I was too lazy to install Qt

Comment: I guess `myCoord` could be an alias for `QVector3D` right?

Comment: Thanks for clarification =) I didn't use `set.insert` in my code. Instead, I just did `std::set<QVector3D> band{ *first, *last };` I wonder what is the equivalent statement after implementing your suggestion.

Comment: Oh, I got it, I just did: `std::set<QVector3D, decltype (customComparator)> band(customComparator);` and then I did: `band.insert(*first);
     band.insert(*last);`

Comment: Or you can also do something like:     std::set<QVector3D, decltype(op)> set({*first, *last}, op); See the available ctors of std::set at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set